# Slice of DataFrame with multi-index by neighbour column value

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Recently, I have started to use pandas for my simple data analysis tasks. So question may be stupid, but nevertheless I have to ask it.

I have data in the following form:

```
                0                   1                   2 
                ix    increasing    ix     increasing   ix    increasing
noname  vtg                         
name1   -0.500  0.000109    True    0.000158    False   0.000153    True
        -0.498  0.000130    True    0.000154    False   0.000158    True
        -0.496  0.000141    True    0.000153    False   0.000158    True
        -0.494  0.000124    True    0.000154    False   0.000154    True
        -0.492  0.000109    True    0.000151    False   0.000154    True
```

and I need to work with 'ix' columns if 'increasing' in corresponding key value is True.

I found just one ugly way to do this:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
qq = data.loc[idx[::, idx[::, 'increasing']]].apply(lambda x: True if all(x) else False, axis=0)
```

and then

```
data.loc[idx[::, idx[list(qq.loc[qq==True].index.labels[0]), 'ix']]]
```

gives all columns 'ix' with True value in 'increasing'. I suppose there should be a pandas like way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possible use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for selecting with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per columns:

```
qq = data.xs('increasing', axis=1, level=1).all()
print (qq)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Then select second level and filter by `loc`:

```
df = data.xs('ix', axis=1, level=1).loc[:, qq]
print (df)
                     0         2
name1 -0.500  0.000109  0.000153
      -0.498  0.000130  0.000158
      -0.496  0.000141  0.000158
      -0.494  0.000124  0.000154
      -0.492  0.000109  0.000154
```

If want also `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = data.xs('ix', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False).loc[:, qq.values]
print (df)
                     0         2
                    ix        ix
name1 -0.500  0.000109  0.000153
      -0.498  0.000130  0.000158
      -0.496  0.000141  0.000158
      -0.494  0.000124  0.000154
      -0.492  0.000109  0.000154
```